# Auto-Running a program from USB flash drive

Tags: autorun, autoplay

I have been up and down the internet looking for ways to configure a flash drive to auto play a file located in its root folder, and just NOTHING seems to work...

Currently, I have a presentation.html file that needs to be started when the user plugs the USB stick in, without any prompt.

I tried several solutions and made sure, multiple times, that my autorun on my system is set on. I created a "autorun.inf" file:

```
[autorun]
UseAutoPlay=1
ShellExecute=presentation.html
ACTION=View the presentation
```

and even tried to configure it to call a batch file "mybatchfile.bat"

```
start presentation.html
```

Nothing seems to work... Each time when the flash drive is plugged in, it prompts me as to what I would like to do with the files "open folder; play with media player; etc...", but will not run the presentation.html.

Any suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try [Super User](http://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a security feature of post-XP windows releases. I am not sure whether it wasn't also in XP. Windows simply won't start content without user wanting so. It will always ask you.